# How do I match everything after @ until space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var str = 'این یک @پیا.م تست است';
// I want this     ^^^^^
```

I can select it like this:

```
/@(.{5})/
```

But it isn't what I need, because the length of that word which is after `@` and before space  isn't always `5`. I really don't know why `\w` doesn't matches Persian characters. Or even `[a-zA-Z]` doesn't work either.

Well, how can I do that?

Comment: `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, `[a-zA-Z]` is for Latin letters, because Persian letters aren’t included in the Latin Unicode range.

Comment: @Xufox Well how can I use Unicode letter in regex?

Comment: You could use: `/@(\S*)/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the follwing regex That will return anything beteen `@` and fot `.` :

**[@(.*?)[\s]](https://regex101.com/r/qK5dC0/4)**

> **@** : matches the character @ literally
>
> **(.*?)** : matches any character (except newline)
>
> **\s** : match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That dot is a part of what I need to select, I want this exactly: `پیا.م`

Comment: You want the word between `@` and `.` + one character?! or between `@` and space?

Comment: No, I want everything between `@` and {space}

Answer (score 4):

As a Unicocde independent approach you can simply use a negated character class :

```
'@([^ ]+)'
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/oD9hV0/1

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way if you have PCRE (which you do in Javascript) is:

```
str.match(/@(\S+)/)
```

That's @-sign followed by at least one non-space. Most of the other character class escapes also have capitalised versions which mean not-this, eg. `\D` for not-digit.

Answer (score 1):

Below regex will work

```
/@(.*?)\s/
```